# Keep creating new child elements on every press on enter

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h2>test for lookup</h2>
    <input type="text" id="someInput" onkeyup=keyup(event) >
  </div>

  <script>
  
    let someInput = document.getElementById('someInput')
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    let childEl = document.createElement('P')

    function keyup(e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 13) {
         container.appendChild(childEl)
         var value = someInput.value
         childEl.innerText = value
         someInput.value = ''
      }
    }

  </script>
</body>
```

Idea is to create a new `<p>` element for each input fill in followed by enter hey.
Now my code is creating `<p>` element, and I get the value inside, but on every press on enter key it gets emptied, and new value is being copied inside.
I want all the previous instances to remain, and for each new press on enter I want to create a new `<p>` with new value.

Comment: It's just logic. If you want to create a new element on every keyup event, call `createElement` in the event handler of the keyup event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `let childEl = document.createElement('P')` inside the if block. `childEl` keeps referring to the same element. Instead, you need to create a new element each time the key is entered instead of changing the already existing one.

Answer (score 1):

As @NumberC has stated quite rightly already, you need to generate a new node each time you use it in your `.append()` method, otherwise an existing DOM element will be moved there and not copied. The following snippet shows my approach with a template object `p`. This object gets modified in the event-listener function with `textContent=...` and then cloned with `.cloneNode(true)` before being processed in the `.append()` call. Please note the way I use the comma operator to execute two expressions and only return the value of the second, the cloned object.

```js
const someInput = document.getElementById('someInput'),
      container = document.getElementById('container'),
      p = document.createElement('p');

function keyup(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    container.append((p.textContent=someInput.value,p.cloneNode(true))); 
    someInput.value = ''
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<h2>test for lookup</h2>
<input type="text" id="someInput" onkeyup=keyup(event) >
  </div>
```

If you can change your HTML structure only slightly then the whole thing can be done much more easily with `.innerHTML+=...`, see here:

```js
  
const someInput = document.getElementById('someInput'),
      container = document.getElementById('container');
someInput.onkeyup=function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    container.innerHTML+='<p>'+someInput.value+'<p>'; 
    someInput.value = ''
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>test for lookup</h2>
<input type="text" id="someInput">
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: As @NumberC had an direct answer to my question I have marked it as a accepted solution. Never the less, yours approach is cleaner and with the given explanation puts a better perspective on how to solve this task. Much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

```
let someInput = document.getElementById('someInput')
const container = document.getElementById('container');
// let childEl = document.createElement('P')

function keyup(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    let childEl = document.createElement('P') // <-- move it here. 
    container.appendChild(childEl)
    var value = someInput.value
    childEl.innerText = value
    someInput.value = ''
  }
}
```